# I want to send the sudo out put trhough a socket

Tags: python, shell

When I send though the socket the command "sudo" the program executes it. However, the pop-up sudo appears on the terminal and it doesn't is sent trhough the socket, so I can't write the password.

So, my question if there is a way to send that "**[sudo] password for marmeus: "** through my socket?, so I will be able to send the password or a alternative way to solve this problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import subprocess
import os

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5555
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print("Conectado!")

while 1:
    #Checking if there is data received through the socket
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    print(data)
    #Execute the commands received
    out = os.popen(data)
    output = output.read()
    if not output:
        s.sendall(" ")
    #Send the output of a command executed
    print(output)
    s.sendall(output)

print("he salido")
s.close()
```

Comment: I guess you need to make `sudo` thinking it is talking to a TTY device. why not use fabric?

Comment: @Marmeus .. would like to explore Fabric, i have a solution there which may be in interest?

Comment: @georgexsh What is fabric ? I don't anything about it.

Comment: @pygo what is fabric & how it works?

Comment: @Marmeus see [this](http://www.fabfile.org)

Comment: there is a problem, fabric must be installed in the client to be executed & I don't want that.